# Testing SQL injection / Drop table not working

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

I am trying to test SQL injection against my site by trying to drop a table(user) and its not working.

my sql string syntax:

```
String sql = "select * from users where username='" + username + "' and password='" + password + "';";
```

I put `jack` in the username field and
`test'; DROP TABLE users; --` in the password field and get the following sql string:

`select * from users where username='jack' and password='test'; DROP TABLE users; --';`
 and then I execute it:

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
```

But its not working, Any idea why?

Comment: Not that I have any experience hacking/spoofing databases, but what is the `--'` doing at the end of the query?  The iniection looks fine up until the `DROP TABLE`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's the comment operator for SQL, I think he/she used it so the last characters won't produce syntax errors. By the way by not working, does it produce errors, or is it just executing but no deletion for the table?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Im so sorry. I check again and looks ok, Rlaw what you mean isnt working? Maybe you miss the error?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza So you're saying who cares whether the `SELECT` returns anything, we only want to slip in the `DROP TABLE`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Yes you only need to make a valid stament closing the password. then the query will execute anything following the `;` and the `--` is to ingore the last `'`. My guess is he already delete the table so the `SELECT`  fail ;)

Answer (score 6):

<strike>password should be:</strike>

```
' OR 1=1; DROP TABLE users; --
```

1. the `'` will close the password string
2. the `1=1` will make sure you found a result.
3. the `--` will comment the last `'` from previous password

**EDIT:**

I made a mistake. Was thinking a diferent hack. The `1=1` is to bypass pasword checking and pass the Login screen.

You only need close the password string

```
'; DROP TABLE users; --
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to add empty space after the comment characters --

So you need to change this:

```
select * from users where username='jack' and password='test'; DROP TABLE users; --';
```

to this:

```
select * from users where username='jack' and password='test'; DROP TABLE users; -- ';
```